# Android trouble with retrofit 2

Tags: android, retrofit2

I'm trying to use retrofit 2.1 in android but I only prints com.example.netapp.Model.PostUpdates@87943a3 7 times as a response. What Am I doing wrong?

**Json**

```
[{
"id": "2",
"categories_id": "2",
"title": "समाज",
"featured_news": "0",
"cover_img": "50D5C03F4C476E718D615DEB3240CCB275E027A2.jpg",
"meta_desc": "एक चीन नीतिमा प्रतिवद्ध छौं: अर्थमन्त्री महरा",
"details": "उपप्रधान तथा अर्थमन्त्री कृष्णबहादुर महरासँग नेपालका लागि चीनका नवनियुक्त राजदुत यु होङले आज अर्थमन्त्रालयमा भेटबार्ता गरेकीछन्।",
"status": "1",
"postdate": "2016-11-18 16:45:16"
},
 ...]
```

**Main Activity Class:**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);


    ApiService api_service = ApiService.retrofit.create(ApiService.class);
    final Call<List<PostUpdates>>  call = api_service.getUpdates("updates");

   call.enqueue(new Callback<List<PostUpdates>>() {
       @Override
       public void onResponse(Call<List<PostUpdates>> call, Response<List<PostUpdates>> response) {
           textView.setText(response.body().toString());
       }

       @Override
       public void onFailure(Call<List<PostUpdates>> call, Throwable t) {
            textView.setText(t.getMessage().toString());
       }
   });


}
```

**ApiService Interface**

```
public interface ApiService{

    String ENDPOINT = "http://localhost/test_api/";

    @GET("api/{param}")
    Call<List<PostUpdates>> getUpdates(@Path("param") String param);


    public final static Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(ENDPOINT)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

}
```

**PostUpdates**

```
public class PostUpdates {

    private String id;
    private String categoriesId;
    private String title;
    private String isFeatured;
    private String featuredImg;
    private String metaDesc;
    private String details;
    private String status;
    private String postdate;
    private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The id
     */
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param id
     * The id
     */
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The categoriesId
     */
    public String getCategoriesId() {
        return categoriesId;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param categoriesId
     * The categories_id
     */
    public void setCategoriesId(String categoriesId) {
        this.categoriesId = categoriesId;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The title
     */
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param title
     * The title
     */
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The isFeatured
     */
    public String getIsFeatured() {
        return isFeatured;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param isFeatured
     * The is_featured
     */
    public void setIsFeatured(String isFeatured) {
        this.isFeatured = isFeatured;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The featuredImg
     */
    public String getFeaturedImg() {
        return featuredImg;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param featuredImg
     * The featured_img
     */
    public void setFeaturedImg(String featuredImg) {
        this.featuredImg = featuredImg;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The metaDesc
     */
    public String getMetaDesc() {
        return metaDesc;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param metaDesc
     * The meta_desc
     */
    public void setMetaDesc(String metaDesc) {
        this.metaDesc = metaDesc;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The details
     */
    public String getDetails() {
        return details;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param details
     * The details
     */
    public void setDetails(String details) {
        this.details = details;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The status
     */
    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param status
     * The status
     */
    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The postdate
     */
    public String getPostdate() {
        return postdate;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param postdate
     * The postdate
     */
    public void setPostdate(String postdate) {
        this.postdate = postdate;
    }

    public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
        return this.additionalProperties;
    }

    public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
        this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
    }

}
```

The android app shows this result
[screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7WimI.jpg)

Comment: which prints the memory address of your object

Comment: print any of the values inside the response using the getter method

Answer (score 0):

Oh! I get it need to use getter method in response body object to get corresponding data. Thanks droidev

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);


        ApiService api_service = ApiService.retrofit.create(ApiService.class);
        final Call<List<PostUpdates>>  call = api_service.getUpdates("updates");

       call.enqueue(new Callback<List<PostUpdates>>() {
           @Override
           public void onResponse(Call<List<PostUpdates>> call, Response<List<PostUpdates>> response) {

               StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
               for(PostUpdates field : response.body()) {
                   sb.append( field.getTitle() + "\n");
               }

               Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: " + sb.toString());
               textView.setText(response.body().toString());

           }

           @Override
           public void onFailure(Call<List<PostUpdates>> call, Throwable t) {
                textView.setText(t.getMessage().toString());
           }
       });


    }
```